# How to use ITK to convert PNG into tensor for PyTorch

Tags: c++, pytorch, itk

I'm trying to run a C++ PyTorch framework and ran into the following problem.

I successfully scripted a model and is now ready to run. Now I have to feed in a `png` image to the model.

I found someone with simmilar issue on the internet, his idea was to use `ITK` module to read in a PNG file and convert it to a array, then make it to `Tensor`.

```
PNG -> RGBPixel[] -> tensor
```

So the following is what I am trying out right now.

```
using PixelTyupe = itk::RGBPixel<unsinged char>;
const unsigned int Dimension = 3;
typedef itk::Image<PixelType, Dimension>      ImageType;
typedef itk::ImageFileReader<ImageType>       ReaderType;
typedef itk::ImageRegionIterator<ImageType>   IteratorType;

typename ImageType::RegionType region = itk_img->GetLargestPossibleRegion();
const typename ImageType::SizeType size = region.GetSize();

int len = size[0] * size[1] * size[2]; // This ends up 1920 * 1080 * 1
PixelType rowdata[len];
int count = 0;
IteratorType iter(itk_img, itk_img->GetRequestedRegion());

// convert itk to array
for (iter.GoToBegin(); !iter.IsAtEnd(); ++iter) {
   rowdata[count] = iter.Get();
   count++;
} // count = 1920 * 1080

// convert array to tensor
tensor_img = torch::from_blob(rowdata, {3, (int)size[0], (int)size[1]}, torch::kShort). clone(); // Segmenation Fault
```

When I try to print log data, it holds three numbers like `84 85 83`, so I suppose the PNG file is successfully read.

However, I can't get the last part of the code to work. What I need is `3:1920:1080` tensor, but I don't think the three RGBPixel value is understood properly by the function.

And apart from that, I don't see why the dimension is set to 3.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need dimension 3, `Dimension = 2` is sufficient. If the layout you need is RGBx1920x1080, then `PixelType* rowdata = itk_img->GetBufferPointer();` would get you that layout without further processing. As `torch::from_blob` does not take ownership of the buffer, the other person was trying to use `.clone()`. You don't have to do that either, assuming you keep the `itk_img` in scope, or muck around with its reference count and `deleter`.

The crash probably comes from saying the buffer has short pixels (`torch::kShort`), when it has `uchar`.